# Simplify the fraction

Tags: fractions

I want to simplify this fraction

$ \frac {1+a+a^2+...+a^n}{1+a^{-1}+a^{-2}+...+a^{-n}} $ where, $ a \in {\mathbb R^*} $ and $ n \in {\mathbb N^*} $

I think is some kind of formula here

Comment: Two geometric progressions. $\frac{\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}}{\frac{a^{-n}-1}{a^{-1}-1}}$

Comment: Wow... I didn't think about that

Comment: You didn't really have to. Just multiply the denominator by $a^n$ and see what happens.

Comment: @IvanNeretin: Please post your comment as an answer, so that it might be accepted, and the question does not clog up the *Unanswered Questions Queue*.

Comment: I didn't expect it to get accepted, since the comment by user236182 pretty much does the job (albeit with an excessively powerful tool). But if you insist...

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really have to use the geometric progression here (though that might help too). Just multiply the denominator by $a^n$ and see what happens.